# Problem with AxesOrigin option in ListPlot

Tags: options, plotting

Please compare the output of these two similar codes:

```
ListPlot[Table[(n + 2)/(3 n), {n, 1, 50}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
ListPlot[Table[(2 n + 2)/(3 n), {n, 1, 50}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I believe this is a bug. I use Mathematica 10.0.2.

Comment: looks fine using M9.

Comment: Indeed in 10.0.2 x-axis is missing.

Comment: a work-around: `Show[ListPlot[Table[(2 n + 2)/(3 n), {n, 1, 50}]], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: There can be problems using All for ListPlot. Try using PlotRange -> Full, or AxesOrigin - > {0,Automatic} and not PlotRange -> All, or AxesOrigin - > {0,All} to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a bug. According to the Help system:

> PlotRange -> All  ........ all points are included

And in both your plots, all points *are* included. If you want your custom location for the axes to be included and visible in the plot, then you need to specify this requirement in the `PlotRange` setting, say:

```
PlotRange -> {0, All}
```

For example:

```
ListPlot[Table[(2 n + 2)/(3 n), {n, 1, 50}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

[image]

... includes All points, starting the vertical from 0, so that the axes location that you have manually specified are visible.

Comment: This might be true, but in general, if you have e.g. a plot of `Sin[a x]` inside `Manipulate` with `a` as manipulated parameter, specifying `PlotRange` will become a nightmare because sometimes you want to use `All` to prevent clipping the negative part, and sometimes you need to specify `0` to make `x` axis visible.