# How can I stop Mathematica from omitting Axes on a Plot?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot something using `Plot[]`, and Mathematica keeps leaving off one of the axes. I can set `Axes->{True,True}`, but one of the axes is still missing. Unfortunately the functions I'm plotting have rather long expressions, and I can't find a shorter example that reproduces the behavior, so I can't show exactly what's going on. What are some possible reasons that Mathematica might leave one of the axes off of a plot, even with `Axes->{True,True}`?

Comment: Are you using `Frame -> True` at the same time?

Comment: Is this the same issue? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79683/5478

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be having a problem with `AxesOrigin` being off the plot.  We can force this to happen by specifying both `AxesOrigin` and `PlotRange`:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

If setting `PlotRange -> All` or `PlotRange -> Full` doesn't do the trick, you can manually specify the origin using: `AxesOrigin -> {x, y}`.

Comment: I just have tried `AxesOrigin -> Scaled[{1, 1}]` and it changes nothing! It seems that `Scaled` specification for `AxesOrigin` does not work!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Confirmed... that's pretty weird.  I think I remember reading another question that explained this behavior, but I can't find it now.  Something to do with the order in which the positions are calculated.

Comment: Is `Scaled` specification for `AxesOrigin` documented? I have tried specifications like `fScaled` but they produce no error messages and changes nothing like `Scaled`. In previous versions incorrect specifications produced error messages, but now there are no messages and nothing happens: incorrect specifications seems to be simply ignored. I do not like this.

Comment: Setting a specific origin worked. It's a little odd that the default origin was off the plot, though, especially since it wasn't on very similar plots.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use `PlotRangePadding`.

Lets take 2012rcampion's answer

```
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> {2, 0}]
```

[image]

You can change the padding range to see when your axes are appearing.

Answer (score -2):

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, -1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

Comment: Are you sure this answers the questions at hand ?

Comment: While this reproduces the issue described, albeit without demonstrating that the ineffectiveness of `Axes -> {True, True}`, it does not address the question asked by the OP.  Consider adding an answer to the question or deleting your answer.

Comment: no axis sure!!!!